# Npm doesn't work in node.js : cannot find module 'D:/test/*'

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working with node.js on my local website and I want to install a module. The problem is npm doesn't seem to be working. For example, if I execute the following command `npm -v`, I have this :

```
D:\test>npm

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\test\*'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:903:3

D:\test>npm -v

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\test\*'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:903:3
```

I am on Windows and I followed the node.js default installation.

Comment: Did you try a reinstall?

Comment: Yes. I tried 4 or 5 times, but always the same error.